# How forgiving are browsers with empty elements written with closing tag?

Tags: html, syntax, xhtml, compatibility

I've seen code that uses stuff like `<input ...></input>` just because there is a bug in Perl `HTML::Zoom`.

How harmful is this syntax when combined with XHTML or HTML5 and common browsers such as Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox?

Have they always been forgiving and accepting this syntax?
How bad is it anyways?

The [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) apparently accepts this as valid XHTML 1.0 Strict, whereas [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element) states that in HTML, *"using a closing tag on an empty element is usually invalid. For example, `<input type="text"></input>` is invalid HTML"*.

On the other hand, [validator.nu](https://validator.nu/) rejects such markup when using HTML5:

```
Error: Stray end tag input.
From line 8, column 20; to line 8, column 27
pe="text"></input>↩</div
```

Comment: In HTML, an end tag for a void element is an error, yes. But it's a very simple error, which is just silently ignored by the parser. Whether it comes right after the void element itself or not, that doesn't matter. Still the same error.

Comment: And in XML, well, `<input/>` is exactly as well-formed as `<input></input>`, so the xml validator doesn't mind. Here it's more a matter of "you really shouldn't" than "it's an error but we'll forgive you".

Comment: Note, by the way, that the W3C validator uses the XHTML parser or the HTML5 parser depending on the content of the file; mainly the doctype declaration. The browsers on the other hand, choose the parser depending on the file type of the file. Files ending in .html will be treated as HTML, regardless of the contents.

Comment: Yes, `<input></input>` is valid XML, but XHTML is a combination of HTML and XML, so I would assume that it should conform to both. And browsers seem to be stricter when XHTML Strict is used, though this seems to mainly apply to XML syntax rather than (X)HTML tags not allowed in the strict flavor.

Comment: The XML parser is much simpler than the HTML parser; it doesn't care for the HTML content, only for the XML syntax. For instance, you can actually create nested <tbody>s in an XHTML file by writing `<table><tbody><tbody></tbody></tbody></table>` and the browser won't throw an error. In HTML this would simply end up as two subsequent <tbody>s.